# Angular2 Material md-button Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I saw earlier that Angular2 launched the RC5 so I decided to update one of my test apps to see the changes and how to adjust. This app is using Material2, I also updated it to Alpha 7.2, but I'm getting this error when trying to use the md-button component

> "Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'md-ripple-trigger' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'div'. ("*ngIf="isRippleEnabled()"
>   class="md-button-ripple"
>   [class.md-button-ripple-round]="isRoundButton()" [ERROR
>   ->][md-ripple-trigger]="getHostElement()" [md-ripple-color]="isRoundButton() ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"):
>   MdButton@0:180 Can't bind to 'md-ripple-color' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'div'. ("ton-ripple"
>   [class.md-button-ripple-round]="isRoundButton()"
>   [md-ripple-trigger]="getHostElement()" [ERROR
>   ->][md-ripple-color]="isRoundButton() ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)' : ''" md-ripple-background-color="rgb"): MdButton@0:219"

I'm using it on a new component I'm trying to add called `nav-bar`, here's the Angular CLI created file with Material added

**TypeScript File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdToolbar } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdButton } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdIcon, MdIconRegistry } from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  templateUrl: 'nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['nav-bar.component.css'],
  directives: [ 
    MdToolbar, 
    MdButton,
    MdIcon 
  ],
  providers: [ 
    MdIconRegistry 
  ]
})

export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HTML File**

```
<md-toolbar>
  <button md-button>
    <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
  </button>
  NavBar
</md-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to import `MdRippleModule` in your `AppModule`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { MdRippleModule } from '@angular2-material/core/core'; <== this line

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, MdRippleModule ], <== add here
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Or pass `MdRipple` directive within your component:

```
...
import { MdRipple } from '@angular2-material/core/core'; <== this line
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  templateUrl: 'nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['nav-bar.component.css'],
  directives: [ 
    MdToolbar, 
    MdButton,
    MdIcon,
    MdRipple <== add here
  ],
  providers: [ 
    MdIconRegistry 
  ]
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
...
```