# Material design component "is not a known element" in Angular2

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have a hybrid Angular1 and Angular2 application. In one of the Angular2 components that I route to, I want to use a Material Design Button.

When I insert a button into the template like this `<md-button>foo</md-button>` the application starts crashing with this console message

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'md-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-button' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h1>Job</h1>[ERROR ->]<md-button>material</md-button>"): JobComponent@0:12
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8321:21)
```

So, it might sound like it is case 1 in the message, but I have tried the advice given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928063/angular2-material-md-button-error) to add `MdButton` to the `imports` property of my `NgModule` (which already contained `MaterialModule.forRoot()` as adviced by [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)) , but if I do, the whole application goes blank without errors in the console.

Here is some of the relevant code

```
import { UIRouterModule } from "ui-router-ng2";
import { Ng1ToNg2Module, uiRouterNgUpgrade } from "ui-router-ng1-to-ng2";

import { MaterialModule, MdButton } from '@angular/material';


const upgradeAdapter: UpgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(
    forwardRef(() => XamFlowNg2Module));

uiRouterNgUpgrade.setUpgradeAdapter(upgradeAdapter);

angular.module("xamFlow")
    .factory("consoleService",
    upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(ConsoleService));


/*
 * Expose our ng1 content to ng2
 */
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider("restService");

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        JobComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        // Components that are routed to must be listed here, otherwise you'll get "No Component Factory"
        JobComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        Ng1ToNg2Module,
        MaterialModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        ConsoleService,
        ImageService
    ]
})
class MyModule { }


upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["myApp"]);
```

Comment: Did you add ` MaterialModule.forRoot(),` to `imports: [...]` of your root `@NgModule()` (https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/fcc5900e496adc5b11e47ad1e6d3e0c2ac2bad9e/GETTING_STARTED.md)?

Comment: Could you please show relevant code ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I did.

Comment: @micronyks added some code

Comment: Hint, `BrowserModule` exports `CommonModule`, there is no need to import both. Use `BrowserModule` on `AppModule` and `CommonModule` on other modules.

Comment: What's the solution if I have the same error with md-icon ?

Comment: Another way is to use class attribute of button element. `<button class='md-button md-raised'> Foo </button>`. Ultimately `md-button` or `md-raised` are css classes.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It should be

```
<button md-button>foo</button>
```

OR

```
<button md-raised-button>foo</button>
```

Comment: Are you saying I can't use `md-` components in the html? I believe you are supposed to be able to do that. Example: https://github.com/kara/leashed-in/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I think Its old way to declare button in material.

Comment: Doh, it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: On the demo page [https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button) it is named `md-button`

Comment: @Guus please check - https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/button/README.md

Comment: @micronyks thanks, the doc i mentioned is probably for angular1

Comment: i use this but i'm sending event to ts file on click when i add the active class it's does not work any help please

Comment: @YaseenAhmed could you please explain your scenario in detail? hard to understand by your sentence. New question would be better...

Comment: This is not true. As you can see in one of their exmamples: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes when you add new component to the angular2 it does't directly register the tag in such cases you have to do 2 things:

Go to app.component.ts file

- 1) Insert manually in "import {component}" the button you want to add
- 2) In the @Component register your component and give the path

Comment: The new component is added in "app.module.js" and it is automatic using  angular cli :"ng generate component aNewComponent"

Comment: Additionnaly it wasn't a custom component problem, (what you describe is a custom component generation) but it helped me to search my case, I should have asked my own question :)