# mat-button is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I don't get it. I think I imported all necessary module, but it keeps telling me:

```
'mat-button' is not a known element:
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-button>foo</mat-button>
```

app.component.scss is empty.

I know there are lots of posts about this. But nothing helped me, because I think I imported everything (`MatButtonModule`) correctly. Anyone an idea what I could do?

Comment: `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';` I think you need to replace this. `<button mat-button color="primary">Login</button>` and you can alse change this with your button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195457/material-design-component-is-not-a-known-element-in-angular2

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It is:

```
<button mat-button>foo</button>
```

not

```
<mat-button>foo</mat-button>
```

**[Official doc.](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview)**

Comment: Oh my... thanks a lot, I gotta give myself a facepalm :D

Comment: @PaulM :'D , Welcome !